# How can i get playing video change in exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a use case in Exo Player to do some task at playing video finish or player finish.
I am using onTrackChange() player internal method on video finish but it is not helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Player.EventListener](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.java#L50) to listen to the state Player.STATE_ENDED:

```
player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
      // end of MediaSource
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
    if (reason == Player.DISCONTINUITY_REASON_PERIOD_TRANSITION) {
      // when window index changes (eg. end of window 0, start of window 1)
    }
  }
});
```

You only need to listen to position discontinuities if you are using playlists and want to be aware when the next playlist item starts ([Medium blog about playlists with ExoPlayer](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/dynamic-playlists-with-exoplayer-6f53e54a56c0)).